# support vector machine in r

Tags: r, svm

I've been working on Support Vector Machine algorithm using R Studio. However, I'm ending up with a low accuracy rate and I don't know how to fix it. I'm expecting an accuracy rate higher than 90%.

Here is my code:

```
install.packages("caTools")
install.packages("class")
library(caTools)
library(class)
install.packages("ISLR")
library(ISLR)

Collegedata<-College[,-1]
Collegedata[,-17]<-scale(Collegedata[,-17])



med<-median(Collegedata$Grad.Rate)
Grad.Rate<-Collegedata$Grad.Rate>=med
Grad.Rate1<-as.numeric(Grad.Rate)
Collegedata<-data.frame(Collegedata,Grad.Rate1)
corcollege<-cor(Collegedata)
Collegedata<-Collegedata[,-2:-3]
Collegedata<-Collegedata[,-4]
Collegedata<-Collegedata[,-7]
Collegedata<-Collegedata[,-13]

SVM
install.packages("e1071")
library("e1071")
collegesplit=sample.split(Collegedata, SplitRatio=0.8)
collegetrain<-subset(Collegedata, collegesplit==1)
collegetest<-subset(Collegedata, collegesplit==0)
collegetrain<-data.frame(collegetrain)

svm.model.college <- svm(Grad.Rate1 ~ ., data = collegetrain, type = "C-classification", cost = 1,gamma = 0.125, cross =10)
svm.pred.college <- predict(svm.model.college, collegetest[,-13])
table(pred = svm.pred.college, true = collegetest[,13])
install.packages('ROCR')
     library(ROCR)
     ROC=predict(svm.model.college,newdata=collegetest)
     ROC<-as.vector(ROC)
     ROC<-as.numeric(ROC)
     pred=prediction(ROC,collegetest$Grad.Rate1)
     perf=performance(pred,'tpr','fpr')
     plot(perf)
     as.numeric(performance(pred,'auc')@y.values)
```

Comment: Have to tried fine tuning the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've coded SVMs so I won't be able to provide you with any code, however, I can say that SVMs are incredibly sensitive to your choice of hyperparameters, e.g. cost and gamma. You'd want to perform a grid search over some sequence of values to determine the optimal values. I recommend using the tune.svm() or best.tune() functions in the e1071 package to do this. Further, while the default Gaussian kernel is often the optimal kernel, it is not guaranteed to be the best, so you could perhaps try the linear kernel instead.

You may find [this paper](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf) useful in helping develop a framework for building your model.